# Jersey: Exception Mapper to validate enum values while marshaling request payload

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey, jackson

Using many enum classes for my rest application. Things likes STATUS, CURRENCY etc are covered using enums.
Right now I have to validate every request at the Rest Controller level against it's corresponding enum value.
Is there a way to catch this error at the marshaling level and handle it via Exception Mapper?

Webservice supports both XML and JSON formats. Xml is taken care by JAXB and Json is implemented using Jackson api.

Answer (score 1):

For what I understand, you are trying to do the same than this :
[Exception mapping from enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531920/jax-rs-jersey-exception-mapping-for-enum-bound-formparam)

So what you are missing might be the `@JsonCreator fromString` method to add in your enum code.